# What's the connection between branchwidth and treewidth

Tags: graph-theory, sat, treewidth, fixed-parameter-tractable, proof-complexity

I understand that treewidth and branchwidth are essentially equivalent for a fixed graph, given that $branchwidth(G) = Θ(treewidth(G))$.

However, my question pertains to a specific case involving Tseitin formulas.

The **underlying graph** of Tseitin formulas is denoted by $G$.

And the **underlying hypergraph** is denoted by $G'$ where each edge in the hypergraph corresponds to a clause of formulas.
$G$ and $G'$ can be seen as dual graphs, although a vertex in $G$ may correspond to multiple edges in $G'$.

**Myquestion:** What's the connection between $branchwidth(G')$ and $treewidth(G)$

My question comes from two papers, in [Characterizing Tseitin-formulas with short regular resolution refutations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.09609), it stated that:

> "The upper bound for this result was already known from [[2]](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/%7Erazborov/files/automat_pos.pdf)
> where it
> is shown that, for every graph G, unsatisfiable Tseitin-formulas with
> the underlying graph G have regular resolution refutations of length
> at most $2^{O(tw(G))}|V (G)|^c$ where c is a constant."

However, upon checking the reference, I noticed that it uses $branchwidth(G')$ rather than $treewidth(G)$.

Comment: They differ by a factor $O(\Delta(G))$ where $\Delta(G)$ is the maximal degree of $G$. In the context of Tseitin formulas, it is usually assumed that the degree is constant, so this factor is dropped.

Comment: @ArturRiazanov  I would like to clarify if the definition of tree decomposition on hypergraph is as shown in  [NEIL ROBERTSON & SEYMOUR .1991.p168.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009589569190061N).  If this is the correct definition, I believe that the tree decomposition you obtained form $G$ to $G'$ by substituting every vertex of $G$ by the variables of the
incident edges may not satisfy condition (ii)

Comment: @ArturRiazanov Oh I understand your comment finally.  step1: for a same graph, treewidth is somewaht equals to branchwidth. step2: For a CNF, the treewidth of underlying hypergraph and primal graph is the same. step3: for Tseitin formulas, the treewidth of its primal graph and underlying grapg just differ by a factor $O(\Delta(G))$